# How to bind a JSOn object in MySQL

Tags: perl

I have a **MySQL** stored procedure sp_foo() that has the following codes:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_foo`(
in p_env varchar(45),
in p_host varchar(45),
in FDs JSON)
```

In Perl, how would I bind a ***Perl*** JSON object to the corresponding stored procedure's JSON **FDs** object?

I've tried different type (including ***JSON_TYPE***) but to no avail:

```
my $logFD = {
uid => 'iib',
  pid => 29115,
  fdCount => 477,
  fdCountMax => 10240,
  program => 'DataFlowEngine',
  parameters => 'DFIB01 da3e3470-a044-4ba6-bf92-f153d1398fdc Logger'
};
my $logFD_json = encode_json $logFD;
$sth->bind_param( $i++, $logFD_json, JSON_TYPE); # <-- this line
```

The error I got would look like:
`Bareword "JSON_TYPE" not allowed while "strict subs"`

Answer (score 4):

There is no such SQL type as `JSON_TYPE`.

MySQL treats JSON values as strings with extra semantics. Since you're already encoding the structure as a JSON string, you don't need to do anything special when binding it as a parameter -- you can safely leave off the third argument to `bind_param`.